# Swift cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'

Tags: swift

So I was trying to write some basic Swift, and I wrote:

```
func timesByHundred(d: Int) {
    return d * 100
}
```

and the compiler said "cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(Int, IntegerLiteralConvertible)'". So I changed it to:

```
func timesByHundred(d: Int) {
    let e: Int = 100
    return d * e
}
```

and the compiler said "cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'". What can I even multiply if not two ints?? There's some similar questions on here but they all have people trying to operate on different types.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler error is misleading.

The real issue is that you missed the declaration of the function return type, so the compiler infers `Void` and it gets confused when tries (and fails) to find a suitable overloading for `*` that returns `Void`.

Change your function to

```
func timesByHundred(d: Int) -> Int {
    return d * 100
}
```

Comment: Swift's compiler errors are truly horrible sometimes. It reminds me of C compilers from the mid 1980s. Maybe even worse because the errors are sometimes not just vague but totally wrong.

Comment: @DuncanC I agree. The main problem is that it often "tries too hard" to make it compile and throws an error when way too deep in the type inference.