# Using numpy with swift throws "cannot invoke '*' with an argument" error

Tags: python, swift, numpy

I plan to use python's numpy in swift as I need to use swift for mathematical calculations. 
The Swift code is -

```swift
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
let x = np.zeros(shape:(1, 2))
```

throws error

```
error: <Cell 3>:2:17: error: cannot call value of non-function type 'PythonObject'
let x = np.zeros(shape:(1, 2))
        ~~~~~~~~^

error: <Cell 3>:2:12: error: cannot invoke 'zeros' with an argument list of type '(shape: (Int, Int))'
let x = np.zeros(shape:(1, 2))
           ^
```

I perused related questions like [Swift cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(Int, Int)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041966/swift-cannot-invoke-with-an-argument-list-of-type-int-int)
 but I dont think they are relevant with regard to numpy.

PS -
I have recently started to learn swift so it is very much possible that I am asking something very basic.

Comment: sorry but this is swift code not python :) please read the question. :)

Comment: I found this simple example of numpy use:  https://gist.github.com/anurlybayev/46812eb25a51e334b01e93fb8893d4b3..Python does allow `np.zeros(shape=(1,2))`, but there must be something about the `swift` syntax that prevents such a translation.

Comment: @hpaulj broken gist link.

Comment: You find it yourself.  I just searched on swift and numpy.  Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you are not calling zeros correctly?

If what you are after is a 2x2 matrix you might want to take a look at the docs for [Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) as it seems you are falsely calling said method

Edit: My suggestion wasn't correct, but still it seems that the error lies in the syntax, take a look at [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/tutorials/python_interoperability#importing_python_modules)

Edit2: As per your comment, here some explanation. (**TLDR** at the bottom)
Edit3: My conclusion below seems to be wrong for the solution see answer by @markroxor below. However the difference between () and [] holds, thus I'll leave the paragraph as is.

I am actually not too familiar with swift so I can't assure you that everything i say is correct, but here goes.
I just assumed the arguments are passed to python in the way they are put into the method call. Now in Python `x = [a,b,c]` will create an object of type list whereas `x = (a,b,c)` will create a tuple. They both are used to store multiple elements which can be accessed via x[index]. The most important difference between them being, that a list can be modified after its creation (`x[0] = z`) while attempting this on a tuple will throw an error. **However this does not apply to Swift (contrary to what i thought at first)**

Now, seeing how python greatly ignores parameter types as long as nothing "illegal" is attempted with them, I thought it was probable that `numpy.zeros()` would not care if it is passed a list or a tuple as long as it contains integers (tested it, no errors). Again this applies for use in python itself only

Now after looking up Swift syntax I would say that the problem/solution is that while Swift and Python seem to handle lists/arrays (Python calls them lists) very similarly the syntax of tuples differs greatly, causing the method call to throw an error when using round braces, thereby creating a **Swift** Tuple which python doesn't know how to handle, whereas the similarity in how arrays/lists work leads to [] being successfully passed to the numpy method
**TLDR**
<del>The difference seems to be that while Python and Swift handle arrays similarly, the implementation of Tuples differs, so that would be the reason using [] works over ()</del>

Comment: Please read the question, this is not python code this is swift. :)

Comment: Thank you, as a beginner I did not notice the difference between round and square braces in swift.

Comment: Often python treats lists and tuples interchangably.  Sometimes `numpy` uses the difference to  provide added functionality. But in `np.zeros` either works.  The `shape` keyword is also optional.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks a lot for the clarification! so it seems my original idea was (at least partially) right after all. 
I couldn't quickly check it as i don't have a Swift environment installed rn

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that whatever you're trying to call isn't a function.

Try using `.call(with:)` instead, so:

```
let x = np.zeros.call(with: 15).shape.call(with: 1, 2)
```

or in whatever function you want to use, I'm not familiar with `numpty` but I have used something similar and had to do it that way with `.call` on some python modules since it's not an indirect function - yet.

Comment: This fails with - `Fatal error: Could not access PythonObject member 'call': file /swift-base/swift/stdlib/public/Python/Python.swift, line 537`

Comment: ```
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
let x = np.zeros.call(with: 15).shape.call(with: 1, 2)
```

Comment: Apply newline as required ^^. Cant use it in comments.

Comment: Okay, just try `let x = np.zeros.call(shape:(1, 2))`

Comment: Please run the code in your environment before suggesting on SO. This doesn't work either. Anyways thank you. Please check the @nightmared 's answer and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

when the body of the closure has an error in it, the compiler will report that it `cannot call the value of a non-function type 'PythonObject'`. By fixing the error in the closure, it will compile.

in *numpy.zeros* **shape** is a parameter that is an **int** or **tuple of ints**, so you just need to change your code to:

```
let x = np.zeros((1, 2))
```

also if you need an "array of arrays" then you can use the following syntax:

```
var matrix = Array(count: 1, repeatedValue: Array(count: 2, repeatedValue: 0.0))
```

This creates a 1 x 2 matrix of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is -

```swift
import Python
let np = Python.import("numpy")
let x = np.zeros(shape:[1, 2])
```

[Notice the brackets].

```swift
let a = [1,2]
let b = (1, 2)
print(type(of: a),type(of: b))
```

yields

```
Array<Int> (Int, Int)
```

Swift is rigid with syntax unlike python, where round and square braces could be used interchangeably when passing to a function most of the time.
`np.zeros` or `np.some_function` takes `Array` as input argument. Hence the need for square brackets.